# how to adjust legend spacing between different legend entries for same legend group?

Tags: python, plotly

For same legend group, how to adjust legend spacing between different legend entries?  For example, below legends for each different times, all these legends are in same group, the spacing is too big, can I make gap or spacing smaller?

[image]